# Clipping polygons in one layer from larger polygon in another layer

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, clip, overlapping-features

In QGIS 3.16.10 I want to clip (remove) the polygon areas (yellow) in one layer from a larger polygon in another layer (gray).

I've tried the Clip from the Processing Tool but it only returns the yellow areas, "*Only the parts of the features in the Input layer that fall within the polygons of the Overlay layer will be added to the resulting layer*", but I want the opposite result (the brown polygon with holes where the yellow polygons are).

[image]

I've also tried the Clipper plugin but can't figure out how to make it work (I'm a novice). I've searched but can only find methods that give the "Clip" result or talk about clipping a raster with a vector polygon. Seems like removing a polygon from another polygon should be easy.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the software package you're using.  But perhaps you're looking for https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Clipper* plugin will work, though it's pretty temperamental.

1. In my case I usually have to merge the layers (then display them rule-based so I can confirm they're all present).
2. Then I hide the large enclosing polygon in the merged layer and select all the smaller polygons I want to cut out.
3. Then I run *Clipper>Clipper Clip with multiple selection*.
   Finally bulk select the entire polygon(s) and deselect the large encompassing one.
4. Then bulk Delete the smaller polygons, which leaves holes (windows) through the larger polygon.

Answer (score 2):

Try the ["Difference"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference) that will do exactly what you want:

> Extracts features from the input layer that don’t fall within the
> boundaries of the overlay layer.

[image: input]

*'Input layer'*: gray
*'Overlay layer'*: yellow

[image: window]

and get the desired output

[image: result]

Comment: The description for Difference indicates it is for removing portions of polygons that partially overlap, not when one polygon is completely within another (as is my case). I've found a way to use Clipper that works. I'll write it up.